# Error deploying App crashed heroku deploy with nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

Hi I have a working node app, when I deploy it I get this error :

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vvat.herokuapp.com request_id=14bca241-fa50-4042-b26e-1235c4abeca0 fwd="85.250.217.223" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

the app works, I have no idea what's causing it, this is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

const app = express();

//connect Database
connectDB();

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/authAPI"));
app.use("/api/maps", require("./routes/api/mapAPI"));
app.use("/api/profile", require("./routes/api/profileAPI"));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));

module.exports = app;
```

what is going on?

Comment: Log the steps in connectDB and check if db is being connected correctly. Add a try catch there to handle it.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty hi the DB is connected remotely to mongoAtlas, it works, and it has a try catch block, so its not from there, maybe something else? because it worked before.

Comment: You only provided the access logs, didn't provide the error stack. So can't locate the issue.